# Action Helper in Ember JS not calling function

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" {{action "toggleStatus"}}><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Add Staff</a>
```

This is in a view template called stafflist.handlebars. The content is as follows

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3>{{staff.title}} <small>List of users who has access to this application</small></h3>
  </div>

<div class="commands pull-right">

sta
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" {{action "toggleStatus"}}><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> {{staff.btnTitle}}</a>

</div>
<div class="pull-left">
<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>ID</td>
</tr>
<thead>
<tbody>
{{#each staff}}
<tr>
<td>{{this.fname}}</td>
<td>{{this.id}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

The View file is as below

```
App.StaffListView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName:'sellap-web/~templates/stafflist',
    staffBinding:'App.staffController',
    toggleStatus: function() {
        alert('Hurray');
    }
});
```

When clicking the button, the action is never calling the alert. What is going wrong here. I am using ember-skeleton to compile.

Comment: If you have a router in your app, then it is the default target of the helper. Could you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: The code is written using RAKE packaging. It packages the whole thing  into a single 50,000 line app.js. I am using ember-skeleton.

Comment: - Do you get an error in the console ?
- You can try to add the view as a target in the action helper.
{{action "toggleStatus" target="view"}}

Comment: Found the culprit. My App.create has a method called init. I changed the name to something else and now it works fine. I didnt call the super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit. My App.create has a method called init. I changed the name to something else and now it works fine. I didnt call the super.